# Object detection vs image difference for finding left object on car seat

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, object-detection

I am confused as to which approach to take, here is the problem.
I am supposed to implement a lost/found module which identifies if passengers using taxi have left something in back seat.
So camera will be placed just above the back seat and once the passenger leaves the taxi, AI module will be triggered which will check if passenger forgot something on seat and alert driver.
Now the problem is - To determine if there is something left, i can use object detection but not all objects would have been trained like in many cases they would just leave covers with something inside. so difficult to quantify that. Then i thot since i could get a image prior to them sitting and then compare it by taking another image after they exit and perform Image difference to find contours. But then there is a possibility of different lighting conditions which could falsely get identified a substantial difference.
[Editted]Also how about image classification rather than detection as im really not interested in the location of object but just to know if object is there

So can anyone please recommend me a good approach to go ahead.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right track. You can go either way, object detection or image classification.

For starters I think you should try image classification. If the main goal is just to know if there is an object there, it's a binary classification problem and you will require much less of a labelling process. You will just need to address the issue of having too many background images (no object) agains too few images with objects in it, but this is feasible. Start with a pre-trained network like a ResNet-50 and see how it goes, you should have pretty good results with this approach.

For object detection, the issue I'm seeing is the amount of possible objects that could be left on the seat and possible variations, yes there are a few common ones, and you can train a network on them, but if there is a completely different object that you didn't train on it, the network won't even detect it. The variations of the object also matter in here, object detection from my experience you need a lot data with various positions and styles of the objects. It's possible, but difficult. To test this, pre-trained models on COCO should give you an overall perspective.

Comment: This sounds great! Thanks for the direction.
ill go ahead with binary classification. Could you please point out a link or some direction to train a already existing basic classifier? Also im planning to use opencv finally to perform the classification. So which model would be better

Comment: OpenCV doesn't support ML model training, you should use Keras from Tensorflow for a quick start. I think this one explains it very well. It's from the official Keras documentation and it's easy to follow. They use an EfficientNet which is a more state-of-the-art architecture. The ResNet50 is always my top choice for a good starting point in my opinion. In the 'import' you just replace the name if you want the ResNet. https://keras.io/examples/vision/image_classification_efficientnet_fine_tuning/#transfer-learning-from-pretrained-weights

Answer (score 1):

There aren't so many type of objects that people can forget on a taxi (phone, wallet, bag, umbrella, key, jacket, hat, ...), so I think object detection would do it's job in more than 99% of the cases.
Otherwise the approach of having a "taxi-prior" doesn't sound so bad. You could use something like histogram normalization to reduce the effects of light variations.

I hope you have a dataset to work on, otherwise the first thing you should do is to collect one.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. If object detection is the way to go, i see there are already many pretrained models for object detection which i think is trained on 80 different classes. so i suppose i can go ahead with that and may be perform retraining to add classes which are not covered like umbrella jacket etc. How about using image classifier which is trained for 1000 classes as im really not interested in location of object.. Any thots?

Comment: It's not trivial (and I don't suggest it) to apply a classifier on a big image where the object of interest can be very small compared to the whole image. It should be quite easy to try a network pretrained on COCO and, depending on the result, you can switch to classification or add categories that are missing in COCO.